# How to hide window when running a Task Scheduler task

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Task Scheduler to execute `python run.py`. It works, but the Python interpreter pops up. I want to run `run.py` in the background without any interpreter popping up.

How can I do this? In Linux I'd just do `python run.py &` to get it to run in the background silently, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same in Windows with Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change **.py** extension to **.pyw**
and the python file will run in background.

And if you want to terminate or check if it actually running in background,

simply open Task manager and go to **Processes** you will see **python32** running
there.

**EDIT**

As you mentioned, this doesn't seem like working from command line because changing the file's **.extension** simply tells your system to open the file with **pythonw** application instead of **python**.

So when you are running this via command line as `python .\run.pyw` even with the **.pyw** this will run with **python.exe** instead of **pythonw.exe**.

**Solution:**

As you mentioned in the comments, run the file as `pythonw .\run.pyw or .\run.py`

or just double click the **run.pyw** file.

Comment: I ended up doing `pythonw run.py` instead of `python run.py` and that worked well

Comment: Well i believe that happens because you are running from terminal instead of doing this try to just double click the file or else go with your approach.